# Build a command and execute it from within a batch file

Tags: code-generation, dos, command-prompt

I have a batch file that outputs a list of commands which themselves can be executed at the command line.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
set %foldername%="c:\my_folder"
set %exename%="c:\my_utility.exe"

cd %foldername%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir *.xml /s /b /a:-d') DO @echo %exename% /x="%%G"
```

This basically outputs a batch file.  It looks like this:

```
c:\my_utility.exe /x="c:\my_folder\file1.xml"
c:\my_utility.exe /x="c:\my_folder\file2.xml"
c:\my_utility.exe /x="c:\my_folder\file3.xml"
c:\my_utility.exe /x="c:\my_folder\file4.xml"
```

I want to execute these commands.  Currently I have to redirect the output to a batch file and then run that.  Is there any way to just say "execute this command I just constructed" in the dos prompt?

Comment: Did you try simply to remove `echo`?

Comment: Doh!  Make it an answer and I'll upvote & accept it.  You are exactly right.

Comment: Don't confuse DOS with some command-interpreter in Windows. DOS is an OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `echo` in the `FOR` loop:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir *.xml /s /b /a:-d') DO %exename% /x="%%G"
```